# Embedding an Expect script inside a Bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `hostname` = 'EXAMPLE' ]
then

/usr/bin/expect << EOD

spawn scp -rp host:~/outfiles/ /home/USERNAME/outfiles/
expect "id_rsa':"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact

spawn scp -rp host:~/errfiles/ /home/USERNAME/errfiles/
expect "id_rsa':"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact

expect eof

EOD

echo 'Successful download'
fi
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and I get an error message:

```
spawn scp -rp host:~/outfiles/ /home/USERNAME/outfiles/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa': interact: spawn id exp0 not open
    while executing
"interact"
```

I don't know what it means and why it doesn't work. However, when I wrote the above code using a not-embedded Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn scp -rp host:~/outfiles/ /home/USERNAME/outfiles/
expect "id_rsa':"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact

spawn scp -rp host:~/errfiles/ /home/USERNAME/errfiles/
expect "id_rsa':"
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

It worked without any problems. So what am I doing wrong?

NOTE: Often when someone posts a question about using Expect to use `scp` or `ssh` the answer given is to use [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) keys. I tried, unfortunately on one of my computers there is some crappy bug with the GNOME keyring that means that I can't remove my password from the RSA key, which is exactly why I'm trying to write the above script with an `if` statement. So please don't tell me to use RSA keys.

Comment: If you want expect to execute **exactly** the text between your delimiter (without variable or special characters expansion before it is interpreted), you'll have to quote your here-doc delimiter, like so : `/usr/bin/expect << "EOD" ... EOD`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc) is similar, it has the same problem but the other way around.

Comment: I just tried it `/usr/bin/expect << "EOD"` but it still gives the error `spawn scp -rp host:~/outfiles/ /home/USERNAME/outfiles/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa': interact: spawn id exp0 not open
    while executing
"interact"
Successful download
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Bash script is passing the Expect commands on the standard input of `expect`. That is what the [here-document](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection?s[]=redirection#here_documents) `<<EOD` does. However, `expect`... expects its commands to be provided in a file, or as the argument of a `-c`, per the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). Three options are below. Caveat emptor; none have been tested.

1. [Process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) with here-document:

   ```
   expect <(cat <<'EOD'
   spawn ... (your script here)
   EOD
   )
   ```

   The `EOD` ends the here-document, and then the whole thing is wrapped in a `<( )` process substitution block.  The result is that `expect` will see a temporary filename including the contents of your here-document.

   As @Aserre noted, the quotes in `<<'EOD'` mean that everything in your here-document will be treated literally. Leave them off to expand Bash variables and the like inside the script, if that's what you want.
2. **Edit** Variable+here-document:

   ```
   IFS= read -r -d '' expect_commands <<'EOD'
   spawn ... (your script here)
   interact
   EOD

   expect -c "${expect_commands//
   /;}"
   ```

   Yes, that is a real newline after `//` - it's not obvious to me how to escape it.  That turns newlines into semicolons, which the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) says is required.

   Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/2877364) for the `read`+heredoc combo.
3. Shell variable

   ```
   expect_commands='
   spawn ... (your script here)
   interact'
   expect -c "${expect_commands//
   /;}"
   ```

   Note that any `'` in the expect commands (e.g., after `id_rsa`) will need to be replaced with `'\''` to leave the single-quote block, add a literal apostrophe, and then re-enter the single-quote block.  The newline after `//` is the same as in the previous option.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used example 1. and it worked. I appreciate it.

Comment: You can also make use of the `-f` flag in `expect` which accepts a file with commands. However, the file could be `-`, resembling `/dev/stdin`. This could be a heredoc. But if the heredoc contains `interact` it will fail as `interact` uses `/dev/stdin` but the heredoc is finished, hence the script terminates.

Comment: Worked on Mac OS X