# How to use expect inside bash script

Tags: bash, expect

Could anybody please tell me why this is not working?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
touch somefile
/usr/bin/expect<<FILETRANSFER
spawn scp -r -P remoteServerPort somefile remoteServerIP:/home
expect "assword:"
send "MyPassWord\r"
interact
FILETRANSFER
echo "It's done"
```

It doesn't give any error but file is not transferred to remote server.I have tried many ways still couldn't find any solution.

Comment: A better way would be to avoid typing or sending any password with `ssh` (also `scp` ). Read some ssh tutorial and use a public key.

Comment: `/usr/bin/expect<<FILETRANSFER`, here you are missing a space before `<<`

Comment: thanks for your replies.
@ Basile Starynkevitch I can't use public key for some reasons.
@ Jahid added space but still not working.

Comment: use `/usr/bin/expect -d` and see what expect is doing.

Comment: This script looks a bit "pseudo" -- are you using shell variables inside the expect body? Normally I would do `expect <<'FILETRANSFER'` where the single quotes effectively quote the entire here-doc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bash script you have defined is passing the expect commands on the standard input of `expect`. However, the `expect` command requires its arguments on a file or as an argument using the `-c` option.

You have several options but to add the less modifications on your script you just need to use the process substitution to create a here-document (temporary) for the `expect` command.

```
#!/bin/bash 

  echo "[DEBUG] INIT BASH"

  cd /home
  touch somefile

  /usr/bin/expect <(cat << EOF
spawn scp -r -P remoteServerPort somefile remoteServerIP:/home
expect "Password:"
send "MyPassWord\r"
interact
EOF
)

  echo "[DEBUG] END BASH"
```

Comment: Btw, I have just checked and there is a SO answer with all the available options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165719/embedding-an-expect-inside-a-bash-script

Comment: No, expect is perfectly fine reading the commands from stdin as posted in the question.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Bourne Shell?

Comment: Actually this same script should work in sh since there is nothing bash dependant.